# How do I limit concurrent session on a per user basis for ssh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to prevent my ssh users from having more than one session open at once, my system is Ubuntu 11.10.

I thought the setting was in `/etc/security/limits.conf` where I set the following:

```
betatest hard maxlogins 1
```

However, this has no effect and I can log in multiple times using user account name betatest from different machines.

The `sshd_config` is using PAM and the login and sshd configs in `/etc/pam.d` both have the setting:

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

If anyone knows how I can restrict the concurrent sessions on a per user basis I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to have a PAM module written to check if the user attempting to login is already logged in and if they are then stop them logging in again?  I don't have the skills for this but if it's possible then at least I have a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me, from the MAN page for pam_limits (at least on rhel/centos), that adding a maxlogins parameter for the desired user(s) would do the trick... but I haven't tested it:

```
NAME
       pam_limits - PAM module to limit resources

SYNOPSIS
       pam_limits.so [change_uid] [conf=/path/to/limits.conf] [debug] [utmp_early] [noaudit]

DESCRIPTION
       The pam_limits PAM module sets limits on the system resources that can be obtained in a user-session. Users of uid=0 are affected by this limits, too.

       By default limits are taken from the /etc/security/limits.conf config file. Then individual *.conf files from the /etc/security/limits.d/ directory are read.
```

Answer (score -1):

Per user setting is very tricky, you might have to write some wrapper script for this. SSHD config has an option **MaxSessions** which limits no of connections per ip.

Comment: The risk is the user will share the login details with friends on different IP's, that's the main issue I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Then proy answer about ssh MaxSessions is your answer

Comment: MaxSessions only limits per ip basis; so it seems will not work

Comment: No, it doesn't limit the no of connections per ip, it limits the number of sessions per network connections. Probably there is no such option in sshd, what I find quite... well... sub-optimal.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for CentOS 7:

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, specify per-user setting like this:

```
Match User foo
    MaxSessions 100
```

Test your config and restart:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -t && systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: This does not limit connections, but sessions inside of one multiplexed connection.