# How can I force logout of other users with same username

Tags: centos, authentication, login, centos7, session

On user login I need to kick all users with same username except for the current one, thus automatically log him out from other ttys. I know that one can kick other users via [slain](https://serverfault.com/questions/3246/how-can-i-force-other-users-to-log-out), but not much more.

Example:

- user1 logs in via session1 => everyone with name user1 has to be kicked out of the system, except for the user in session1 => nothing happens because user1 is the first user to log in
- user1 logs in via session2 => same attempt to kick other user1s is performed as in previous step => user1 in session1 is kicked out of the system

Comment: Different users cannot have the same username.  Perhaps you mean that when an user logs in, you want him to be automatically logged out from other ttys?

Comment: Possibly [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/q/367906/37681) is of use.

Comment: @HBruijn, thanks, but I need to force log outs, not limit their number.